# How to extract all characters after the 30th in simple string.

Tags: regex

I have a text field that returns a string of characters from 38 to 40 long. I need to just extract from the 30th character to the end.

I used .{9}$ to grab the last nine, then realized that the original strings are not a set amount of characters and only the first 29 is not needed. Everything after is the case number and is what I need. Again the number of characters needed can be anywhere from 9 to 12 long

Comment: Doesn't replacing `^.{29}` with empty string work?

Comment: If you need to get a series of digits at the end of the string, then do `[0-9]+$` or `\d+$`. But it would be easier if you would provide sample strings together with the expected output.

Comment: Please note the contradiction here: *"a string of characters from 38 to 40 long. I need to just extract from the 30th character to the end. "* and *"number of characters needed can be anywhere from 9 to 12 long"*.

Comment: Example string = e39875ythg98jskla73019kmjuhbe0okujhbgt4  Expected output = e0okujhbgt4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Skip the First 29 and Extract the Rest

Here are string methods [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), [`.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), and [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). A RegEx that'll skip the first 29 characters and spaces then extract the rest is:

```
(?:[\s\S]{29})([\s\S]*?)
```

- Start matching non-capture: `(?:`...
- Any space or non-space character: `[\s\S]`
- Twenty-nine times: `{29}`
- End matching non-capture: ..`)`
- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
- Next, start matching capture: `(`...
- Any space or non-space character: `[\s\S]`
- Zero or more times: `*`
- Lazily: `?`
- End matching capture: ...`)`

---

### Demo

```js
var str = '123456789㉈123456789㉉123456789㉊123456789㉋';

var rgx = /(?:[\s\S]{29})([\s\S]*?)/;

console.log('var str = ' + str);

console.log('--------------------------------------------------');

console.log('str.slice(29) // ' + str.slice(29));

console.log('--------------------------------------------------');

console.log('str.substring(29) // ' + str.substring(29));

console.log('--------------------------------------------------');

console.log(`var rgx = ${rgx}`);

console.log('str.replace(rgx, "$1") // ' + str.replace(rgx, '$1'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.as-console-row-code.as-console-row-code {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is the only code that worked out of all of the replies. So appreciated!!!  I guess that is why you must weed through all the answers.  Most of them either only extracted up to the 30th character and some just extracted the whole string.

Comment: That's great, @Michael_Weingand glad I could help, remember to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of this post ✅

Answer (score 0):

you can use substring function

```
[YourString].substring(29)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Python, simply do:

```
string[30:]
```

This will automatically return the thirtiest character to the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
^.{30}\K.*$
```

> **^** asserts position at start of the string
>
> **.{30}** Quantifier — Matches exactly 30 times
>
> **\K** resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
>
> **.*** matches any character (except for line terminators)
>
> **$** asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)